# Is jhipster the only solution that allows to generate pages and fields connected to DB?

Tags: javascript, java, frameworks, javascript-framework, jhipster

Jhipster allows you to add new entities & relations. By doing this you get new pages with custom fields ready for use literally in minutes.

Is there some other solution/generator that provides this functionality while not being that complex? Jhipster is great but tough for beginners and is an overkill for a simple web app like mine.

Background: I'm building a simple web app that allows users of two kinds to interact with each other (one group can create offers, other group can view existing offers and accept some if they like).

Comment: What are your non fonctional requirements? In terms of language and platform? Complexity is a subjective metrics but if you want to keep it simple  I would suggest you don't build a single page application, so that you can focus on server side and a single technology stack.

Answer (score 0):

Try grails.org. It can generate pages by defining only the entities (domain). And i think it is a bit easier to learn.

Answer (score 0):

After hours and hours of web-surfing I discovered [Play framework](https://www.playframework.com/) which seems to be less complex and more user-friendly framework for java newbies (like myself).
Unfortunately it doesn't provide the functionality of entity generation but at least it feels like I'll be able to customize it myself to an extent which covers my needs.